# How to push an array property in json-server

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, json-server

I have a working hours manager frontend that's being built with a json-server mocked data and the API has this structure:

```
{
    "workers": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "Raphael Alvarenga do Carmo",
            "dayPunchings": [
                {
                    "day": "7/25/2021",
                    "timePunchings": [
                        {
                            "id": 1,
                            "idWorker": 1,
                            "type": "Arrive",
                            "time": "7/25/2021, 8:05:00 AM"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 2,
                            "idWorker": 1,
                            "type": "Lunch",
                            "time": "7/25/2021, 12:00:00 PM"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 3,
                            "idWorker": 1,
                            "type": "lunchReturn",
                            "time": "7/25/2021, 1:00:00 PM"
                        },
                        {
                            "id": 4,
                            "idWorker": 1,
                            "type": "Exit",
                            "time": "7/25/2021, 5:00:00 PM"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**Question**

How can I push one more working day in dayPunchings property?

**What I've tried**

I tried:

1. Following the JSON structure to build the URL like:

> http://localhost:3000/workers/1/dayPunchings/

2. Changing request methods between POST, PUT and PATCH.

**Results**
None of them worked. All I did that worked would be adding the whole object again through the /workers URL. But it's not good since I'm sending the whole object again to update only one property.

**Note**
I usually create backend before frontend but I didn't have a choice this time and that's why I'm having to use this lib. I appreciate any help/suggestions.

Comment: It's not obvious to me what you're trying to do. For one thing, why does changing the request method make any difference?

Comment: Judging by the comments [here](https://github.com/typicode/json-server/issues/1056) and in the linked topics, I'd say what you want is not supported

Comment: Thank you @Phil . I suspected the same but didn't find a source where a could get a confirmation.